# Trying to understand how formik package for react is constructed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of learning React. I tried the Formik package https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik for React. It seems to work nice.

However, I tried to understand how it actually works with no luck.

Here is an example of simple form made with Formik:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
const FormikShort = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Formik example</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{email: '', password: ''}}
      validate={values => {
        let errors = {};
        if (!values.email) {
          errors.email = 'Required field';
        } else if (
          !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email)
        ) {
            errors.email = 'Not valid email address';
          }
        return errors;
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          setSubmitting(false);
        }, 400);
      }}
    >
    {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting}) => (
      <Form noValidate>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="emailLabel">Input email address</label>
          <Field className="form-control" type="email" name="email" />
          {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </Form>
    )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

export default FormikShort;
```

So in the example above there is an anonymous function call between Formik-element opening and closing tags. What makes this possible?

If I create my own simple component, such as

```
function Dummy(props) {
  return <h1>Dummy component: {props.text}</h1>;
}
```

And then have it rendered like this

```
<Dummy
  text="hello"
>
  <div>Some text</div>
</Dummy>
```

the text "Some text" is not rendered at all. What do I have to do in order to be able insert stuff inside my own component and have it show up?

What about the function call inside the Formik-elements opening and closing tags? Where do the values for parameters (errors, touched, isSubmitting) come from?

I tried to look at the source files at node_modules/formik but I don't know exactly what file to look at. There are a lot of files, such as:

- formik.cjs.development.js
- formik.cjs.production.js
- formik.esm.js
- formik.umd.development.js

Comment: children are in ... `props.children`.   Why not looking at [sources](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/src/Field.tsx) ?

Comment: I looked at the sources at node_modules/formik but it's full of node related stuff so yeah, it's definetely better to look at source at github. Thanks for the push into  right direction!